# Does Flask-Login support roles?

Tags: flask, roles, flask-login

If not, are there any projects that have added this feature to Flask-Login? Otherwise, it appears to be a bit daunting to migrate from Flask-Login to Flask-User. Otherwise, is there any sort of direction out there for migrating from Flask-Login to Flask-User?

Comment: https://github.com/raddevon/flask-permissions

Comment: Unfortunately, that project is no longer supported and after installing Flask-Permissions via pip, it does not recognize the Github page's suggested import.

Comment: you might want to check Flask Security, which has support for roles

Comment: @gittert als Flask Security is no longer mantained.... you have to check Flask Security-too what a mess...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Again, answering my own question here for anyone else curious how you can add the feature of handling multiple roles while still using Flask-Login. I created the below decorator which just checks the `current_user.role` to see if it is `"Admin"`. You should also check the same thing when letting the user log in, depending on if they are logging in to the admin or the user panel.

```
from functools import wraps

def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.role == "Admin":
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("You need to be an admin to view this page.")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return wrap
```

Comment: how to add role to the User Object. i tried hardcoding role at the time User object creation to see if i can fetch it from current_user. but i get - AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'role'

Comment: Old question but I wonder how you test this with pytest. What ever I tried, I have a NoneType for current_user.role (in the decorator code), while current_user.is_authenticated (in the test code) behaves as expected. Of course when I run the application the decorator works as expected (only a test issue)