# Flask authentication and authorization

Tags: flask

I'm trying to build a flask application that requires authentication, authorization, role and permission management, email confirmation and change password.
I found some extensions like flask login, flask user, Flask-RBAC and others but I'm not sure what to use especially I want to use this in production. So please what should I use to have a viable solution?
I think flask login is well maintained but it does not provide all requirements.

Comment: How about [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) or [Flask-Security 2](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html). Both will meet your needs. They are based on several extensions, Flask Login being one of them.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have privileges to add a comment, and this is not an answer to the question and more in the nature of a comment, but in researching the same topic the above recently posted question came up quickly in my search results, and as of the date of my post there is only one short suggestion/comment here, yet the topic has in my view generally been covered fairly in depth already elsewhere. I found these posts (most preceding the one above) to be more useful and substantive for evaluating Flask tools for handling authentication, authorization, roles and permissions.
Non-exhaustive list:

- [Flask-Login vs Flask-Security for Production Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71621225/flask-login-vs-flask-security-for-production-environment)
- [How to implement role based access control in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549476/how-to-implement-role-based-access-control-in-flask)
- [Flask user-roles, authorization, login and security, or principal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228714/flask-user-roles-authorization-login-and-security-or-principal)
- [Flask user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972999/flask-user-authentication)
- [Role based authorization in flask-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939800/role-based-authorization-in-flask-login)
- [How to implement role based access control in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549476/how-to-implement-role-based-access-control-in-flask)
- [Does Flask-Login support roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285012/does-flask-login-support-roles)